# Entity Framework savechanges - can't see changes in other clients

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using EF 4.0 with VS2010. I have 2 clients running my applicaion.
When I save the changes in one client, I see them in the SQL server, but the 2nd client doesn't see them.
I need to restart the application to see the changes.
I'm using a Data layer for all the DB stuff, I leave my connection open all the time (as suggest in some post I read) might it be the problem??? any workaround I can't write the DL from scratch again.

10x

Comment: why do you leave the connection open? That doesn't sound like something you should do.

Comment: What is the actual "Data Layer" you mentioned is it sql server on the intranet or a local sql express database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default if an entity is loaded to the context that instance is returned when you query the database for a set of entities which will include the above entity.

You need to set the [MergeOption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectquery.mergeoption.aspx) to `OverwriteChanges` to get the changes in the database.

```
context.Products.MergeOption = MergeOption.OverwriteChanges;
var products = context.Products.Where(/**/);
```

Its better to create short lived to contexts to avoid such problems.

Comment: Do I need to do "context.Products.MergeOption = MergeOption.OverwriteChanges;" before each call to the DB Or can I set it once??

Comment: @Kulpemovitz all subsequent queries will be affected. So be careful, you may not want that setting all the time.

Comment: Well, I need the clients to show the same data. It is a  Production Management application. what is the worst scenario of "So Be Careful" ??

Comment: @Kulpemovitz say you make a change to an entity and before calling `SaveChanges` you query the database in such a way that changed entity will be included in the returned result. Then the changes will be lost.

Answer (score 1):

EntityFramwork isn't updating data when you change it on other connection. To get new state you have to recreate Context and load all data again.